# Dragging files out of web page into your local disk?

Tags: javascript, file, html

I just read [this blog post](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/06/25/googles-html5-plans-for-gmail-include-1-second-to-inbox-startup) and it stated that:

> Google is now working on reversing the
> process -- allowing us to drag files
> out of Gmail messages and drop them
> onto our local folders.onto our local folders.

My question is: how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't — in current browsers.

It will require browsers to implement an API to make it possible and for pages to make use of that API. That, presumably, is what Google is working on.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Perhaps you are right. Let's see what others have to say.

Answer (score -1):

Google has its own browser so it is possible with Google Chrome.